# Google Chrome Folder Drag and Drop Support

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, webkit

in Google Chrome 7 Folder drag and drop has been added [click-here](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2010/10/bringing-another-chrome-release-to-you.html), Can any one show demo code how is that possible?